# nodeID from geo location OSRM

Tags: nodes, openstreetmap, osrm

I'm running a local OSRM instance with c++. Is there a way to get NodeID for a location specified by Longitudes and Latitudes?
Also, for 2 nodeIDs how can I find the distance and duration between the two nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to get NodeID for a location specified by Longitudes and Latitudes?

Yes using the `nearest` service.

Example: `http://router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037`

Will return:

```
{"waypoints":[{"nodes":[2264199819,2045820592],"hint":"KRMKgOFPZoYfAAAAOgAAAAsAAAAAAAAAHwAAADoAAAALAAAAAAAAAP3nAAAATMwAqVghAzxMzACtWCEDAQDfCv6mfdg=","distance":4.085340532788629,"name":"Friedrichstraße","location":[13.3888,52.517033]}],"code":"Ok"}
```

Where the `nodes` properties includes the OSM ids.

> Also, for 2 nodeIDs how can I find the distance and duration between the two nodes?

There is currently no way to use OSM Node ID directly as input for OSRM. You will have to obtain the coordinate first, maybe using the OSM API?

Comment: Thanks for the response, But what I want is given 2 nodeIDs (not geo locations) is there a way to get the distance and duration between those nodeIDs.

Comment: Never thought of using the OSM API. Will look into that. Thanks for the help :)